# C# How to programatically set/clear selections and cursor position in PowerPoint?

Tags: c#, powerpoint, office-interop

I am currently working on a read aloud application that highlights text as it's being read. The text highlights are specified in character indices.

`TextRange range = Application.ActiveWindow.ShapeRange.TextFrame.TextRange` gives me a range containing all characters in the current shape.

I've not been able to find a way to set `Start`and `Length` of `TextRange` directly (they're read-only) so I've resorted to using `range.Characters(start, length).Select()`.

So far, so good. Problem is I can't use this to clear the selection, because I can't find a collapse function for the range. In Word I've done it by settings `Start = End` on the range object - which also places the cursor at this position.

How can I do the same in PowerPoint?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm so stupid - I only just figured out how to use `range.Characters()` 5 minutes ago. Just as I posted the question the answer dawned upon me:

```
range.Characters(start, 0).Select();
```

This method can be expanded to work on the entire PowerPoint document by looping through all shapes:

```
foreach (Slide slide in app.ActivePresentation.Slides){
    foreach (Shape shape in slide.Shapes)
    {
        if (Shape.HasTextFrame == MsoTriState.msoTrue)
        {
            // Do stuff with this part of the text
        }
    }
}
```